# "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" when sending value as login.username_textbox('redacted@gmail.com')

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting the error below when sending value as login.username_textbox('redacted@gmail.com'):

```
(LoginTest.test_login_valid)
self = <class 'test.LoginTest'>

    @classmethod
    def test_login_valid(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get('chrome://settings/clearBrowserData')
        driver.get(self.base_url)
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        login = LoginCrm(driver)
>       login.username_textbox('redacted@gmail.com')
E       TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

test.py:23: TypeError

Assertion failed
```

**My code is below:**
**pom page:**

not able to paste the code so attaching them in image.:

[image: PyCharm]

**Main test class:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import unittest
from loginPages import LoginCrm

class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):
    a = {}
    # @classmethod
    # def setupclass(cls):
    base_url = "https://example.com"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.maximize_window()

    @classmethod
    def test_login_valid(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get('chrome://settings/clearBrowserData')
        driver.get(self.base_url)
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        login = LoginCrm(driver)
        login.username_textbox('dhruboisbd@gmail.com')
        login.password_textbox('12345678')
        login.login_button_click()
```

Comment: The formatting of your post looks broken.

Comment: Seems that `username_textbox` wants a function and not a string. However without seeing the method I can't say more.

Comment: have added the code image in link not able to attach the code formatting is getting bad.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, `username_textbox` is a string attribute on instances of the `LoginCrm` class. I believe you actually mean to call `enter_username`, e.g.:

```
login.enter_username('redacted@gmail.com')
```

Comment: i gave them as enter_username as well. Still i got the same error.i renamed them stilll am getting the same error.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same error? Can you provide the traceback?